# Apple Safari keep html changes after page reload

Tags: html, safari, reload

I am using the web inspector in Apple Safari browser to alter the html code of a website in Safari. Is there any way to keep the changes after reload of the page?

I want to add reload button in a specific part of the page. I don't have problem with that but I want the button to stay there after reload.

Comment: Why aren’t you adding your change in the html file itself, instead of in the dev tools? @Tomáš Janulík

Comment: Oh, I should have made that clear - it's not my website.

Comment: check my answer @Tomáš Janulík

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apple Safari keep html changes after page reload

Every web browser, when it reloads a page, always resets the HTML to its original and re-executes any JavaScript code.

> I am using the web inspector in Apple Safari browser to alter the html code of a website in Safari.

What you've changed is the rendered page in the web browser. You're changing in-memory data in your computer, not the HTML file.

> Is there any way to keep the changes after reload of the page?

No. You'll have to edit the HTML file separately. With the default web browser features, the closest thing you can do is by using HTML/JS playgrounds such as JSFiddle or JSBin.

However, you can create a HTML application similar to JSFiddle, but you won't be editing the HTML file directly.

Not sure if there is a Safari equivalent - but there is Emmet LiveStyle for Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emmet-livestyle/diebikgmpmeppiilkaijjbdgciafajmg?hl=en

You'd be better off editing the actual file itself, though - and last time I tried LiveStyle I seem to recall it wasn't overly stable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that and the reason for that is that you are editing the page on the client-side. So every time you refresh, the browser fetches the website from the server-side, undoing all of your temporary changes. If you are simply just doing this for some practice, I would recommend copying the code from the inspector and adding it to your own HTML file, and then make any changes to that file.

Answer (score 0):

In Safari as of ~January 14, 2020 you can keep HTML changes by Creating a "Response Local Override". So when you refresh the page, it will act like the request returned your modified HTML source file.

[More info here](https://webkit.org/web-inspector/local-overrides/)